# Would 'play drums' and 'play drum set' be allowed in North American English in certain settings?

Tags: definite-articles, north-american-english, zero-article

So far the discussion about 'play + the + (the name of a musical instrument)' as opposed to 'play + (the name of a musical instrument)' is hotly held at places, and it seems the version without 'the' is used mainly in the U.S. in the following settings:

1. when you are talking about what part in a band, an orchestra, etc. you play,
2. when you are answering a question like 'What do you do for a living?',
   and
3. when you are saying that you are 'practicing' the instrument.

I want to pick your brain with regard to '***drums***' and '***drum set***.' Do the same weak tendency for the above apply to this as well? Maybe I should ask the speakers of North American English ....

Any and all comments would be welcome.

**EDIT: Everyone, after re-reading what I read to include the 'practice' factor as a condition for the 'the-less' usage, I would like to take it back. I think I misinterpreted the reading.**

Comment: As English speakers tend to be quite lazy, 'drums' is much more common. 'Drum set' would hardly ever be used, except maybe to say "I'm buying a drum set".

Comment: @Inazuma Thanks. My focus is actually on the tendency in American English to go without 'the' in certain situations regarding the instrument in question. But thanks any way.

Comment: Normally it would be "play drums", since few percussionists use only a single drum, so "play the drum" doesn't really work.  And the percussionist might gripe about having to haul his drum set around in his old VW van, but he would rarely if ever "play the drum set".

Comment: @Hot Licks, how about 'play the drums,' though? You may say 'I play drums' in one of the three possible situations, but other than that would you say 'I play the drums'?

Comment: @Sssamy Yeah, "play the drums" would work too.

Answer (score 1):

The following are acceptable:

> I play drums.
>
> I play the drums.
>
> I play the drum set.
>
> I play the drum kit.
>
> I drum.

The following are unacceptable:

> I play drum set.
>
> I play drum kit.
>
> I play drum.

If you have only one drum, the following is appropriate:

> I play the drum.

The comment posted by @Inazuma is correct, in that *drums* is more frequently used than *the drum set*. The term *the drum set* is used particularly when distinguishing between other forms of percussion, and carries a certain level of formality with it.

In the following conversation between two musicians, for example:

> Person A: "I play the djembe. What about you?"
>
> Person B: "I play the drum ***set***."

This is because *drums* and *drum set* are not necessarily synonymous.

Definition of *drum*, according to [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/drum?q=drums):

> 1. noun : A percussion instrument sounded by being struck with sticks or the hands, typically cylindrical, barrel-shaped, or bowl-shaped with a taut membrane over one or both ends.
>
> 1.1 (drums) A set of drums.
>
> 1.2 (drums) The percussion section of a band or orchestra.
>
> 1.3 [singular] A sound made by or resembling that of a drum:
>   the drum of their feet.
>
> 1.4 (historical) : A military drummer.

Definition of *drum kit*, according to [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/drum-kit?q=drum%20set):

> (also drum set)
>
> noun : A set of drums, cymbals, and other percussion instruments used with drumsticks in jazz and popular music. The most basic components are a foot-operated bass drum, a snare drum, a suspended cymbal, and one or more tom-toms.

In other words (...or photos), a *drum set* looks like this (or some version of this):

[image: drum set image]

But, *drums* may describe this:

[image: bongo drums]

or this:

[image: timpani drums]

or this:

[image: drum set image]

So, *drums* is an umbrella term that includes *the drum set*, but *the drum set* refers to a fairly specific type and configuration of drums. But, when the average American thinks of *the drums*, they almost always think of *the drum set* (since, in the U.S., the drum set is by far the most popular form of drums).

---

All information in this answer is based on my understanding of American English.

Comment: [All information in this answer is based on my understanding of American English]
Thanks, Kyle, for your so thorough explanation. Much appreciated. So you are a speaker of American English. Correct?

Comment: @Sssamy Correct. The three examples in your original post are ambiguous enough that either _the drums_ or _the drum set_ fit.

Comment: 'I play drums' and 'I play the drums' --- the dividing line is where you are in one of the situations I described above and other situations. Is that correct, more or less?

Comment: @Sssamy No, it isn't so narrowly defined. You can use _the drums_ or just _drums_ in any of your three example situations. They mean the same thing. There are no rules that explicitly dictate the usage.